# Linked list issue with ARM processor

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I'm trying to create a linked list in C to run on an ARM processor (not sure about exact processor specs, but `-mcpu=arm7tdmi` is passed to compiler) using GCC. Here's the code:

```
#include <posapi.h>
#include <posapi_all.h>

const APPINFO AppInfo={
    "POS-Simple example",
    "APP-TEST",
    "1.0",
    "pcteam",
    "demo program",
    "",
    0,
    0,
    0,
    ""
};

typedef struct st_dllNode {
    struct st_dllNode * next;
    struct st_dllNode * prev;
    void * data;
} dllNode;

typedef struct {
    dllNode* first;
    dllNode* cur;
    uchar size;
} ListContainer;

typedef ListContainer* List;

List createList(void)
{
    List listContainer;
    listContainer = (List) malloc(sizeof(ListContainer));
    listContainer->first = NULL;
    listContainer->cur = NULL;
    listContainer->size = 0; // exception occurs here
    return listContainer;
}

int event_main(ST_EVENT_MSG *msg)
{
    SystemInit();
    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    List list;
    SystemInit();
    while (1)
    {
        list = createList();
        free(list);
        Beep();
    }
}
```

For unknown reasons, execution of this code stops on the line marked, and the device I'm using begins dumping an exception message:

```
PrefetchAbortHandler:2007FFC4,AA...... (more addresses follows)
PrefetchAbort Addr: (another addr); Status:02020a01
```

I have no idea why this code runs perfectly fine in Windows, but when compiled for ARM, gives such an error. Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside: Do you *really* think `typedef ListContainer* List;` makes the code easier to read? I think using typedefs just because you can makes things unreadable. This was the very thing that led to the earlier confused/incorrect comment by another user.

Comment: @ArjunShankar Indeed I do. Sorry for the confusion :(

Comment: So how does using `listContainer` and `ListContainer` make it easy to read?

Comment: A prefetch abort means you're trying to _execute_ invalid memory - I'd guess it's actually the following return statement generating it, implying some previous code has smashed the stack.

Comment: @Notlikethat I'm sure about the line which throws the exception because I have incremented and displayed a counter on a 7-segment display attached to my equipment between every two lines of code. And BTW, thanks for the hint

Comment: What is `uchar`? I hope that this is not `unsigned char*`?

Comment: @codemonkey it is named `size` so it is probably an unsigned integer type meant to hold small sizes. i.e. `unsigned char`. But this also demonstrates why possibly unnecessary use of typedefs can be confusing.

Comment: @codemonkey Updated code. The reason for these abbreviations is that, this is part of a much larger application with lots of such `typedefs` and `definitions`. I'm not responsible for coding style... I just have to follow it due to company policy :(:(

Comment: @iManBiglari Have you tried compiling the smallest possible program that reproduces this bug? I don't see a `main` here. It would be nice if you whittled the code down to a couple of dozen lines that we can all see in their entirety. Right now, nobody here knows what calls `createList`. What we're looking for is: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @ArjunShankar updated code to the smallest form possible

Comment: @iManBiglari I tested the code on a Linux system and there are no problems. Maybe you do something wrong with the initialization of the processor? However could you please take a look in the header and post the typedef of `uchar`? If `uchar` is also a pointer that is the problem. Alternatively you could try to change `uchar` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @codemonkey `#DEFINE uchar unsigned char`

Comment: OK. So this is not the problem.

Comment: `malloc` always succeeds, right? No repro on my ARM Linux machine (cross-compiled with Linaro 13.08 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc). Anyway, if that last output is a dump of the IFSR then it looks like a misaligned PC, which suggests either the return address is trashed or GCC has generated buggy ARM/Thumb interworking code. Or of course something hilariously catastrophic like somehow managing to overwrite an interrupt handler.

Comment: It looks like malloc doesn't always succeeds.

Comment: @auselen You're right... I tried `malloc(1)` and it returns `NULL`. Apparently this device does _not_ have heap memory, or doesn't like to share it with my application :(

Comment: It's probably not a good malloc and that's all. Your code is not error safe. That's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Try to add one barrier() or similar macro function in your code.

Details:

```
List createList(void)
{
    List listContainer;
    listContainer = (List) malloc(sizeof(ListContainer));
    smb();      // this is Linux memory barrier API. Replace it with your OS similar API
    listContainer->first = NULL;
    listContainer->cur = NULL;
    listContainer->size = 0; // exception occurs here
    return listContainer;
}
```

Reason: The target ARM processor may execute code out of order. 
listContainer may not be alloced successfully, but "listContainer->size = 0" is executed first of all.

Comment: Isn't the solution then to check the return of `malloc` rather than to place a memory barrier...?